# Strange result with bitshift operations

Tags: c

I am trying to understand bishift operations better so I wrote myself a little program.

```
unsigned char a = 240;
a= (a << 3) >> 7;
printf("a: %u\n",a);
```

Now I would imagine that the result would be something like :

```
11110000 // 240
10000000 // << 3
00000001 // >> 7
```

So 1, but I get 15. I am confused... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You've tagged this as both `c++` and `c`. Which is it?

Comment: You could do this: `((a << 3) & 0xFF) >> 7`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that this statement : `(a << 3)` converts the input to an `int` . So at this point you have `240 * 2 ^ 3 = 1920`

```
00000000000000000000011110000000
```

Then you are dividing the previous result by `2 ^ 7 = 128` so you have : `15`

```
00000000000000000000000000001111
```

Which is exactly what you are getting as a result.

If you wanted to truncate bits you could have used :

```
printf("a: %u\n",a & 1); //get only last bit so you would have 1 as a result!
printf("a: %u\n",a & 255); //get all 8 bits
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: The other solution, of course, is a cast back to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

The expressions are evaluated as (unsigned) ints. (default int promotion). Casting(truncation) to a narrower type only happens just prior to the final assignment.

Answer (score 3):

When you shifted, it casted `a` into an integer type larger than 8 bits, so the top 4 bits were saved

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned char a = 240;
    a = (a << 3);
    a = (a >> 7);
    printf("a: %u\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

prints 1

Answer (score 1):

While shifting the types are automatically promoted to int which is wider than char (most often). So, it can store all your bits.

To get what you expect you would have to do

```
a = a << 3;
a = a >> 7;
```

or

```
a = ((unsigned char)(a << 3)) >> 7;
```

Comment: ... or even `a <<= 3; a >>= 7;`.